# unexpected end of json while parsing near '...+eATxtf+G1Wn3\nTYqat"

Tags: node.js, npm

We updated some of our packages and now the build breaks with the message "unexpected end of json while parsing near '...+eATxtf+G1Wn3'"  What's the fix?

Answer (score 0):

Remove package-lock.json and node_modules and re-run npm install.

Answer (score -1):

add package-lock.json to .gitignore

Comment: No. Never do this.